# Can non-serializable and non-parsable objects be sent from a RemoteService to an Activity?

Tags: android, android-service, inter-process-communicat, android-service-binding

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) makes use of the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)
classes to pass data between a remote service and the activity. This however limits the data sent to serializable and parseable classes which can be sent through a Bundle.

Is there a method of passing non-serializable and non-parsable objects?

Comment: I think no. Those method are used to recreate the object at the received side. If you don't to pass a non-serializable, you can write it down to file and read it again.

Comment: As I understand, the OS don't direct pass your objects and view to another process, they actually create 2 different object at both process and transfer the data between them.If you use it inside your application process, you can pass anything into Message.obj between service and activity. But to the other process, the object must be Serializable or Paracelable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after researching this further it seems impossible to communicate any non-serialized or non-parcelable object to or from a view. The closest it gets seems to be [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) which are a parcelable view that seems to be able to be sent across processes.